# Pass data from ViewController to class

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, arkit

I'm quite new to Swift and I'm struggling with this issue. I want to pass the size and point of `squareImage` to a different swift file in my project using `setSquareRec`.

View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SceneDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var squareImage: UIImageView!

    var scene = Scene()

    func setSquareRec() {
        scene.x = Int(squareImage.bounds.minX)
        scene.y = Int(squareImage.bounds.minY)
        scene.width = Int(squareImage.bounds.width)
        scene.height = Int(squareImage.bounds.height)
    }

    ...

}
```

The class:

```
protocol SceneDelegate{
    func setSquareRec()
}

class Scene: SKScene {

    var width = 0
    var height = 0
    var x = 0
    var y = 0

    ...

    let ARViewController = ViewController()
    ARViewController.setSquareRec()

}
```

It gives me the error `Thread 5: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` in the first line ( `scene.width = Int(sqareImage.bounds.minX)` ) of the function `setSquareRec`

How is it possible that is has no value?! And how is it possible to pass it to another class? I looked at so many solutions but none of them worked or I don't get it.

Comment: did you connect the iboutlet of sqrimage from storyboard ?

Comment: That is because you called `setSquareRec()` before the views are loaded in the viewController.

Comment: Yes I did. @RatulSharker

Comment: @MarwenDoukh when are they loaded? I couldn't find the order of how swift compiles the code because there's no main function. As you notice I'm a noob at swift

Comment: @caddarina you are not implementing the delegate properly

Comment: @Caddarina, I invite you to read this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview

When you initiate the viewController using `ViewController()` you are not initiating the views

Comment: @MarwenDoukh thanks for your answer. I added the line `loadView()` into my setSquareRec` function before I set the attributes for scene, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Your ViewController have a `Scene` property that has been initiated , and that is right , BUT your scene should not initiate the viewController. inside it.

I mean the viewController should initiate its components.

Comment: check my answer and try if not working let me know

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate your view controller with `let ARViewController = ViewController()`.

Try inflating it from a storyboard.

Feel free to ask if it isn't clear.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not clear to me. What does inflating mean? I'm not a native speaker (and especially no professional programmer)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using your delegate is wrong infact you are not using the delegate itselg. Kindly look at the approach below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SceneDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var squareImage: UIImageView!

    var scene = Scene()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //set delegate for scene as this delegate
        scene.sceneDelegate = self
    }

    func setSquareRec() {
        scene.x = Int(squareImage.bounds.minX)
        scene.y = Int(squareImage.bounds.minY)
        scene.width = Int(squareImage.bounds.width)
        scene.height = Int(squareImage.bounds.height)
    }
}

protocol SceneDelegate{
    func setSquareRec()
}

class Scene: SKScene {

    var width = 0
    var height = 0
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
    var sceneDelegate: SceneDelegate?

    ...
    //call this delegate method like this
    //This will call the setSquareRec method to any class who is set as delegate
    sceneDelegate.setSquareRec()
    ...
}
```

not tested kindly test let me know incase of any issue

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code and it gave me the same error.
I also tried another suggestion by adding `self.loadView()` into the first line of the function `setSquareRec()` additionally to your code. But it failed also...

Comment: please you share the code where you are loading the view controller

Comment: Okay I think there is the problem. I never initialize a ViewController except once in the class `Scene` (as you can see above) so I can use the `setSquareRec` function. A friend of mine gave me his code for an AR App. In his code he never initializes  a ViewController and the App still worked.